# replace old-link-url to new-link-url with sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, debian

I'm writing a script in bash that would replace old-link-url to new-link-url
my problem is that sed can't replace the url because of the slashes. If i put just some text it works.

my code

```
sed -e s/"$old_link"/"$new_link"/g wget2.html > playlist.txt
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sed` supports *any* character as separator, so if the pattern you are trying to replace contains `/`, use a different separator. Most commonly used are `#`  and `|`

```
sed  's|foo|bar|g' input
sed  's#foo#bar#g' input
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to put `double quotes` if you are using `variables` in `sed` substitution. Also, if your variable have `/` then use a different delimiter for `sed`. You can use `_`, `%`, `|`, `#` and many more.

So may be something like this would work -

```
sed -e "s_"$old_link"_"$new_link"_g" wget2.html > playlist.txt
```

Comment: When you say `many more` do you mean any character I want, or is there a list of accepted separator characters?