# How to escape colon and double slash in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am writing shell script to replace a line a file which has an URI.I am getting error in using URI.

Line to be placed:

```
   source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

My script:

```
   #sed -i '1s/.*/  source 'https://rubygems.org' /' /Gemfile
```

It is not able to identify single quote.

Error i am getting: **"sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unknown option to `s'"**

Comment: Beware of mixing your quotes like that, you want to replace a line with double-quote in it, not with single-quote, you say.

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace old-link-url to new-link-url with sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544226/replace-old-link-url-to-new-link-url-with-sed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use something like this instead.

```
sed -i "1s,.*,  source 'https://rubygems.org' ," /Gemfile
```

Double quotes around the sed script to allow internal single quotes and `s,,,` instead of `s///` (since you can use just about any single character for the delimiter that you want).

Answer (score 2):

You can use alternate delimeters in your sed command.

For example, years ago I had a sed line that had to swap URLs and I used the @ at sign.

For an example, create a text file 'file.txt' with the following:
    I have a unix operating system from California

Run the following in your shell, using the @ instead of the usual slash delimiter.

```
$ sed 's@unix@linux@' file.txt
I have a linux operating system from California
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` accepts different separators:

```
sed -i '1s|.*|  source "https://rubygems.org" |' /Gemfile
```

And within single quotes you can also use double quotes.